# Confusion about inner product spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

I have an exercise like below

> Let $X$ is an inner product space and $\forall u,v \in X$. Show that if $<x,u>=<x,v>$ then $u=v$ for $\forall x \in X$

What did I do

$<x,u>=<x,v> $ $\Rightarrow$ $<x,u>-<x,v>=0=<x,u-v>$

But if $x$ is unit of $X$, $u$ and $v$ don’t have to be equal. In addition, cannot both of $u$ and $v$ be orthogonal to $x$ when they’re not equal? Is there some missings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have it worded strangely.  I would say: “Let $X$ be an inner product space and $u$, $v \in X$.  Show that if $\left<x,u\right> = \left<x,v\right>$ for all $x\in X$, then $u=v$.  And is $X$ finite dimensional?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang $X$ is any inner product space. I have written what did I see

Comment: Ah, OK.  I guess you don't need it.  Notice that $\left<x,u\right> = \left<x,v\right>$ means that $\left<x,u-v\right> = 0$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: Apart from the bad quantifier disorder... you can let $x$ be anything, so the trick is to think of letting $x=u-v$...

Comment: Thanks for comments I got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\langle x, u - v\rangle = 0$  for all $x\in X$. Now take $x = u - v$.

Comment: Thanks a lot I have just seen it